# Missing file tex\generic\dehyph-exptl\dehypht-x-2017-03-31.tex?

Tags: miktex

After un update from april 9, 2018 I cannot run miktex (pdflatex) on any document.

I get a complaint about a missing file

```
tex\generic\dehyph-exptl\dehypht-x-2017-03-31.tex
```

of which I know nothing about. MikTeX tries to install from the net and then fails. No output. My file is not in German and I do not require german hyphenation.

It tells me to look at initexmf.log and this is what I see:

```
2018-04-10 08:43:59,808+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6634 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
2018-04-10 08:43:59,808+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2018-04-10 08:43:59,808+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2018-04-10 08:43:59,808+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx
2018-04-10 08:44:39,692+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed. The process output has been saved to a file.
2018-04-10 08:44:39,692+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1", savedOutput="C:\Users\Vianello\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2018-04-10-084439.out"
2018-04-10 08:44:39,692+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\initexmf\initexmf.cpp
2018-04-10 08:44:39,692+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 303
2018-04-10 08:45:34,231+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6634 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
2018-04-10 08:45:34,231+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2018-04-10 08:45:34,231+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2018-04-10 08:45:34,247+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx
2018-04-10 08:46:48,682+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed. The process output has been saved to a file.
2018-04-10 08:46:48,682+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1", savedOutput="C:\Users\Vianello\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2018-04-10-084648.out"
2018-04-10 08:46:48,682+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\initexmf\initexmf.cpp
2018-04-10 08:46:48,682+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 303
2018-04-10 08:46:55,080+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6634 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
2018-04-10 08:46:55,080+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2018-04-10 08:46:55,080+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2018-04-10 08:46:55,096+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx
2018-04-10 08:47:34,614+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed. The process output has been saved to a file.
2018-04-10 08:47:34,614+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1", savedOutput="C:\Users\Vianello\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2018-04-10-084734.out"
2018-04-10 08:47:34,614+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\initexmf\initexmf.cpp
2018-04-10 08:47:34,614+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 303
2018-04-10 08:54:31,192+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6634 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
2018-04-10 08:54:31,192+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2018-04-10 08:54:31,192+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2018-04-10 08:54:31,198+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx
2018-04-10 08:56:04,304+0200 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed. The process output has been saved to a file.
2018-04-10 08:56:04,305+0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1", savedOutput="C:\Users\Vianello\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2018-04-10-085604.out"
2018-04-10 08:56:04,305+0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\initexmf\initexmf.cpp
2018-04-10 08:56:04,305+0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 303
2018-04-10 08:56:09,207+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6634 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
2018-04-10 08:56:09,207+0200 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2018-04-10 08:56:09,207+0200 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2018-04-10 08:56:09,213+0200 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx
```

Comment: I solved the problem by manually editing language.dat language.def etc and writing 2018 where I saw a 2017 , as suggested elsewhere. Now it works, but I do not understand how the issue came about.